# Method undefined? Cannot use yield

Tags: node.js, mongoose, bcrypt

I want to yield a process. However, I get the error: You may only yield a function, promise, generator, array, or object, but the following object was passed: "undefined".

Not sure why.

Mongoose method:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
 bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    if (err){
       return cb(err);
     }
    cb(null, isMatch);
 });
};
```

Usage:

```
yield user.comparePassword(this.request.body.password, function(err, isMatch) {
    console.log(isMatch);
});
```

The error occurs when in usage. user is not null or undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `comparePassword` doesn't return anything, that's why you get an error about it yielding `undefined`.

Let's assume that you want `comparePassword` to return a promise. That means that you need to wrap `bcrypt.compare()`—which uses callbacks—with a promise, and return that promise:

```
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword) {
  var user = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, user.password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(isMatch);
    });
  });
};
```

This is how you'd use it:

```
yield user.comparePassword(this.request.body.password); // no callback
```